# How to find pinch zoom direction in android?

Tags: android, zooming, gesture

I have implemented pinch to zoom in my app.Normal zoom in and zoom out are working fine. But if i zoom out while zooming in(without taking hands off from canvas) it is returning scale factor greater than 1 only. So i am not able to do he calculation properly.Is there any way to find out the zoom direction other than checking scalefactor value greater than 1.0 or not?

Answer (score 0):

For determining in/out direction you can compare

```
detector.getCurrentSpan();
detector.getPreviousSpan();
```

For determining horizontal/vertical direction you can compare

```
detector.getCurrentSpanX();
detector.getCurrentSpanY();
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me

```
private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener
{
  @Override
  public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
  {
    mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
          // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
    mScaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_SCALE, Math.min(mScaleFactor, MAX_SCALE));
    //Log.d(TAG, "factor = " + mScaleFactor);

    updateTextSize();
    return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with direction ?